# Wie würde man "easy come, easy go" übersetzen?

Tags: english-to-german, idiom, meaning-in-context

Meine Kinder haben mich gestern nach der Bedeutung von *"easy come, easy go"* im Text der Bohemian Rhapsody von Queen gefragt. Dort heißt es:

> *I'm just a poor boy, I need no sympathy
>
>   Because I'm **easy come, easy go***

und später:

> ***Easy come easy go** - will you let me go*

Mir ist dazu nichts Passendes eingefallen. Wie würdet Ihr die Redewendung hier übersetzen?

Comment: http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=easy+come%2C+easy+go - keine Zeit 'ne Antwort zu schreiben.

Comment: @JohnSmithers: The OP is asking about *(meaning in context)*, is not hard to look up the alternatives in dictionaries, is it?

Comment: @Gigili: scroll down to the "Forumsdiskussionen".

Comment: @JohnSmithers: Keine Zeit nach unten scrollen.

Comment: @Gigili: Would have saved you the time writing the comment ;)

Comment: Bismillah!! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Im Wörterbuch](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/easy_come,_easy_go) findet man folgende Definition für *easy come, easy go*:

> etwas erlangen und wieder verlieren, meist zeitnah; eventuell wird ein Zusammenhang postuliert; oft nach dem Verlust benutzt

Die übliche deutsche Übersetzung ist die Redensart

> wie gewonnen, so zerronnen

Die Textstelle würde ich etwas lyrischer auf folgende Weise übersetzen:

> Ich bin nur ein armer Junge, ich brauch kein Mitleid
>   Heute mir, morgen dir.

im Sinne eines Vagabunden *("bohémien")*, dem nicht viel an Stetigkeit liegt.

Das Lied - eine Ballade - stellt übrigens den Monolog eines jungen Mannes dar, der einen Mord begangen hat und wie er damit umgeht.

Comment: `Heute mir, morgen dir` finde ich sehr holprig, aber `heute hier, morgen dort` kaum besser. Das `easy` findet sich auch im `leichten Mädchen` welches aktiv heute kaum noch gebraucht wird (`Schlampe`), aber passiv sicher von jedermann verstanden wird - eine vergleichbar griffige Formulierung für maskuline `Leichtmatrosen` liegt mir gerade nicht auf der Zunge. `Bruder Leichtfuß` vielleicht?

Comment: Ich finde "heute hier, morgen da" auch besser als das zusammengeschusterte "heute mir, morgen dir". Wenn es sich nicht zu reimen bzw. ins Versmaß zu passen braucht, wäre "leicht zu kriegen, leicht zu verlieren" recht nah am original und verständlich.